# Is there something wrong with my Rainer cherry tree?

Tags: plant-health, fruit-trees, plant-care, cherries, sap

[image]

[image]

I just noticed this sap at the base of the Rainer Cherry tree (I think, I didn’t plant it I just noticed the cherries). I don’t believe I hit it with anything but it’s possible the weedwacker hit it. Is this bad? Is it diseased? Can I save it and how?